# Jquery after updating ".attr" value "onclick" will show old value

Tags: jquery

i'm trying to update the data-checkbox-name with this:

```
$(document).on("click", ".selectBtnAdmin", function(e)
{
    $(".selectBtnAdmin").removeClass("selectedBtnAdmin");
    $(this).addClass("selectedBtnAdmin");
    var id = this.id;

    $("tr").each(function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });
    $("tr.head").show();
    $("input").attr("checked", false);

    if (id == "aktiv")
    {
        $("tr.aktiv").each(function() {
            $(this).fadeIn(400);
        });
        $("input.selectall").attr("data-checkbox-name","#1");
    }
    else if (id == "inaktiv")
    {
        $("tr.inaktiv").each(function() {
            $(this).fadeIn(400);
        }); 
        $("input.selectall").attr("data-checkbox-name","#2"); 
    }
    else if (id == "deaktiviert")
    {
        $("tr.deaktiviert").each(function() {
            $(this).fadeIn(400);
        }); 
        $("input.selectall").attr("data-checkbox-name","#3"); 
    }
    else if (id == "angenommen")
    {
        $("tr.angenommen").each(function() {
            $(this).fadeIn(400);
        }); 
        $("input.selectall").attr("data-checkbox-name","#4"); 
    }

    $("input.selectall").data("checkbox-name", "#2");
    $("input.selectall").data("data-checkbox-name", "#2");
});
```

This works one time fine for me, but if i want to get the new value after a secound change of the "data-checkbox-name" it will show me the old one - so not "#3", but "#2".

```
$(document).on('click', ':checkbox.selectall', function(){
    alert($(this).data('checkbox-name'));
});
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: what is selectBtnAdmin ????

Comment: What's in the `if(...)`?

Comment: Use `.data` to set the value - ie `$("input.selectall").data("checkbox-name", "#2")`

Comment: The "selectBtnAdmin" is a div class, which triggers the function on click.

Comment: The if(...) is to see which div with the class "selectBtnAdmin" has been clicked and to change the data value to the right one.

Comment: `$("input.selectall").data("checkbox-name", "#2")` wont work, it dont changes the value. Sorry.

Comment: If `.data(name, val)` doesn't work, then you might be doing something else that you've not included here.  This is a working fiddle showing it set the data value and reading the data value:  https://jsfiddle.net/k7a4h5f6  update, using an input incase it makes a difference (it doesn't) https://jsfiddle.net/k7a4h5f6/1/

Comment: I updated the post, this is all what i'm doing - and it won't work. - Thank you for your fiddle example.

Comment: Can you put together a jsfiddle to reproduce?

Comment: What version of jquery are you using?

Comment: Also, `$().attr` and `$().data` don't mix together.  jQuery stores `$().data()` values in an internal buffer for quicker extraction.  If you set via `data` then `attr` then read via `data`, you won't get the updated value.  Use either `attr` or `data` not both.  If you use `data` then don't prefix your value with "data-".  Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k7a4h5f6/2/

Comment: Added another update showing changing via attr after reading via data does not change data: https://jsfiddle.net/k7a4h5f6/3/   in short, don't mix attr and data (which you are) - `$.data(name)` is always the first value that is read unless set via `$.data(name,val)` https://jsfiddle.net/k7a4h5f6/4/

Comment: I'm using the latest version of Jquery `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>`

Comment: I can try to put it together in jsfiddle - but this takes a moment.

Comment: I only mixed `$().attr` and `$().data` to show you that i implemented it right. But i try it again.

Comment: It works now- the trick was, that the `.data(name, val)` dont changes the HTML - what i expected. I also changed the other function to the `.data` function, which takes me to success. Thank you all.